# Counting immediate repeated letters in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code which will read sentences from a file and the count the repeated letters and store it as string in another file as an output.

The problem is that the code will only count one repeated letter and will not store the others...

Repeat.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Repeat {

    public static String text;
    static String vector = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Formatter output;

        try {
            Path p = Paths.get("G:\\sarcasm\\out2.txt").toAbsolutePath();
            output = new Formatter(p.toString(), "utf-8");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get("G:\\sarcasm\\repeatinput.txt"), "utf-8");

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                String lineout = new String();
                List<String> filtered = Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s"));
                String result = "";

                //loop through each word in the sentence, peeking at the next and comparing it with the current word
                Map<String, Integer> letterCount = new HashMap();
                int sLen = line.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < sLen; i++) {
                    String currLetter = String.valueOf(line.charAt(i));
                    String nextLetter = i + 1 < sLen ? String.valueOf(line.charAt(i + 1)) : "";
                    // check the next word, if it matches, update the map count
                    if (currLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(nextLetter)) {
                        if (!letterCount.containsKey(currLetter)) {
                            letterCount.put(currLetter, 1);
                        } else {
                            letterCount.put(currLetter, (letterCount.get(currLetter) + 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (String key : letterCount.keySet()) {
                    result += " Letter " + key + " appears " + letterCount.get(key) + " times";
                    if (key.equals("ا")) {
                        vector = letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector = "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ب")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ت")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ث")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ج")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ح")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("خ")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("د")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ذ")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ر")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ز")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("س")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ش")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ص")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ض")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ط")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ظ")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ع")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("غ")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ف")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ق")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ك")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ل")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("م")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ن")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ه")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("و")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("ي")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("!")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals("?")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals(".")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ", ";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0, ";
                    }
                    if (key.equals(",")) {
                        vector += letterCount.get(key) + ".";
                    } else {
                        vector += "0.";
                    }

                }


                output.format("%s\n", vector);
            }
            input.close();
            output.close();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException excp) {
            System.err.println(excp.getMessage());
        } catch (FormatterClosedException excp) {
            System.err.println(excp.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException excp) {
            System.err.println(excp.getMessage());
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

and the input file is:

> اهلا وسهلاااا بكمم!!
>
> يا اهلاااا ومرحببااا
>
> كككيفكم???
>
> هههههههههههههه

And the output i got is:

> 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
>
> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
>
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0.
>
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.

Where it should be:

> 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.
>
> 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
>
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0.
>
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.

How could i solve this?

Comment: What happened when you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you you made it over complicated. I removed all the unnecessary codes and coded a clean solutions with using 2 lists.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Repeat {

    public static String text;
    static String vector = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String line = "اهلا وسهلاااا بكمم!!";
        List<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        vals.add("ا");
        vals.add("ب");
        vals.add("ت");
        vals.add("ث");
        vals.add("ج");
        vals.add("ح");
        vals.add("خ");
        vals.add("د");
        vals.add("ذ");
        vals.add("ر");
        vals.add("ز");
        vals.add("س");
        vals.add("ش");
        vals.add("ص");
        vals.add("ض");
        vals.add("ط");
        vals.add("ظ");
        vals.add("ع");
        vals.add("غ");
        vals.add("ف");
        vals.add("ق");
        vals.add("ك");
        vals.add("ل");
        vals.add("م");
        vals.add("ن");
        vals.add("ه");
        vals.add("و");
        vals.add("ي");
        vals.add("!");
        vals.add("?");
        vals.add(".");
        vals.add(",");

        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>(vals.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {
            results.add(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            String s = "" + line.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < vals.size(); j++) {
                if (i < line.length() - 1) {
                    if (vals.get(j).equals(s) && vals.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("" + line.charAt(i + 1))) {
                        results.set(j, results.get(j) + 1);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println(results);

    }

}
```

That gave me output

```
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```